# How cosign finds a record in Rekor when verifying?

Tags: cryptography, digital-signature, code-signing

From what I understand, when you sign an image/binary using `cosign`, a record is created in Rekor that is used a proof that the signature took place at a specific time.

What I was wondering is: when verifying, how does cosign locate the record in Rekor?

Let's take an example of blob signing.

I sign an artifact using:

```
cosign sign-blob  file.txt --output-certificate fulcio.crt.base64 --output-signature fulcio.sig
```

this takes me to do OIDC authentication, and outputs the certificate used for signing as well as the signature.

Now, for validation:

```
cosign verify-blob --certificate fulcio.crt.base64 --certificate-oidc-issuer=https://accounts.google.com --certificate-identity xxx@gmail.com --signature fulcio.sig file.txt
```

When validating, the validator passes to cosign:

- The file
- The signature
- The certificate used to sign the blob
- The identity it expects to sign the blob
- The OIDC provider

What in this bunch of data tells cosign how to locate the record in Rekor?